# Popup positioning over buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a non-clickable button made with jQuery Mobile on the bottom right corner of my screen. I am trying to get my popup to appear on top or a bit above and to the left of this button.

Currently I am trying to test out jQuery mobile's positioning functions window, origin, or #myelement. However which ever option I pick, the popup always pop ups in the middle of the screen. I am not sure what I am doing wrong because I believe I am following the examples correctly.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="StatusButtons">
<a href="#CS_popup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="origin" data-icon="GhCsStatus-Red" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-role="button" id="GhCsStatus_CS" style="display: none; pointer-events: none;">CS</a>
<a href="#GH_popup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="origin" data-icon="GhCsStatus-Red" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-role="button" id="GhCsStatus_GH" style="display: none; pointer-events: none;">GH</a>
</div>  

<div id="GH_popup" data-role="popup" >
    <p> GH is OFF! </p>
</div>

<div id="CS_popup" data-role="popup" >
    <p> CS is OFF! </p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () { GrabGhCsStatus(); });

    var CScount = 0;
    var GHcount = 0;
    var GHCScount = 0;

    function GrabGhCsStatus() {
        var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("index","GhCsStatus"))';
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            if (data.CheckIfCsIsRunning == 1) {
                $('#GhCsStatus_CS').show();
                if (data.CsStatus == 0) {
                    $('#GhCsStatus_CS').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'GhCsStatus-Red' });
                    if (CScount == 0) {
                        $('#CS_popup').popup("open");
                        CScount = 1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $('#GhCsStatus_CS').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'GhCsStatus-Green' });
                    CScount = 0;
                    //alert("CS:1/green");
                }
            }
            else {
                $("#GhCsStatus_CS").remove();
            }

            if (data.CheckIfGhIsRunning == 1) {
                $('#GhCsStatus_GH').show();
                if (data.GhStatus == 0) {
                    $('#GhCsStatus_GH').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'GhCsStatus-Red' });
                    if (GHcount == 0) {
                        $("#GH_popup").popup("open");
                        GHcount = 1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $('#GhCsStatus_GH').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'GhCsStatus-Green' });
                    GHcount = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                $("#GhCsStatus_GH").remove();
            }
            // Set timeout, if CS or GH is enabled.
            if (data.CheckIfCsIsRunning == 1 || data.CheckIfGhIsRunning == 1) {
                window.setTimeout(GrabGhCsStatus, 5000); //120000); // 2 minutes
            }
        }, "json");
    }
</script>
```

Here is a jsfiddle to a jist of my project code:

http://jsfiddle.net/liondancer/nC2dm/1/

I can't seem to recreate the error in jsFiddle. This error only occurs in my code. I try to simplify the code in the jsfiddle but it seems to be working properly. However, on my project it does not work properly.

If anything else is needed, feel free to ask for more! Thank you

Comment: Please provide a working JSFiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/nC2dm/19/

Comment: @Omar my buttons in this project are not supposed to be clicked. They are simply notification icons actually =/